# MacBook Air Fan Problems

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Air fan is producing excessive air when it isn't hot whenever I open it even after I have restarted it, shut it down, and force quit everything many times and it won't stop. I cannot play any sound out loud or through my headphones. I don't really know what to do and need my laptop for school. It's been like this for a week now.

Comment: What apps are running when this happens? If you shut it down, then restart _and don't use it_ do the fans still spin up?

Comment: Just Safari, and yes the fans start to build up almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an app called smcFanControl. It's a nifty little program that can directly control the speed of your fan.
You can also check the CPU temperatures to see what's making it hot - if indeed something is. Even when it gets hot it can take a while to cool down again.
It's usually something in the background that causes this.
Open Activity Monitor in Utilities, and click on the CPU tab, so that the programs that are running show up with the heaviest users first. That will show you what's using most resources, and thus causing your fan to run.
Things like iCloud, Dropbox, Photos updates as they synchronise with the cloud services can also cause a lot of activity, thus overheating the system and causing the fan to overrun.

Comment: What if it isn't hot and how to I get it to stop after checking my Activity monitor?

Comment: Did you install smcFanControl? That should be able to stop it for you. Or at least set it back to a reasonable speed. You still need some air moving or it will get really hot and die. Did you find out what's using most resources from ActivityMonitor?

Answer (score 0):

First look if something is really heating it up or is it a fake.

Open Activity Monitor and look for highest CPU user and then for highest Energy Consumption to find out.

Here is a sample from my Mac (not running hot)

[image]

[image]

If CPU is <100 % and Energy consumption is normal, then it is a Fake (no heat).

There is a device (a chip) in your Mac called System Management Controller (SMC) that controls the power (battery) and Temperature sensors (Fans).

The SMC needs sometimes to be RESET so to operate normally.

**Important** is to actually see the confirmation that SMC was reset properly.
When you are doing the SMC reset procedure, carefully monitor the MagSafe (plug) light, it has to briefly change color.

How to reset SMC depends on your Mac model, [and here are Apple instructions.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Please do not install any 3D party software like "smcFanControl" it does not do any good to your Mac.